# Insert slot into a component instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have `Component1`

```
<template>
<div> <slot></slot> </div>
</template

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

and `Component2`

```
<template>
<div> {{ someProp }} </div>
</template

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        someProp: String
    }
}
</script>
```

and I want to create those components dynamically with

```
var Comp1 = Vue.extend(Component1)
var Comp2 = Vue.extend(Component2)

var instance1 = new Comp1()
var instance2 = new Comp2()
```

How do I set/insert the Slot for `instance1` as `instance2`? My instinct was to do this

```
instance1.$slots.default = instance2
```

But in the DOM, the slot in `instance1` shows up as `undefined`.

Comment: Not sure it will work, but the name of the property is `$slots`, so try `instance1.$slots.default = instance2` and let us know how it goes

Comment: Okay just looked back at my code and it was a typo in the question, I do have $slots with an s.

Comment: Can you show what you want to do with `instance1` or `instance2`? I have a hint, but I need to test it...

Comment: @acdcjunior It's super complicated. I have a canvas that displays a waveform as a bunch of rendered rectangles. I can highlight a group of those rectangles. When I click on the highlighted group, I want to create another canvas with just the highlighted group that I can then drag off and drop somewhere else. My canvas is controlled with Konva `v-stage`, `vlayer` and `v-rect` templates. I want to store these in a component and create the full canvas on the fly anywhere on the page based on certain conditions, as many times as I need. Do you still want to see the code?

Comment: You're right, I don't ️. Try calling `instance1.$mount()` right after setting the `instance1.$slots.default` and before appending `instance1` to the DOM.

Comment: I actually already tried that and other permutations of the same code. Before, after, in-between. I tried setting the slot as an array, as the instance, as the $el. You can create instances and append them to the DOM. I feel like there has to be a way to do that without breaking slots.

Answer (score 0):

is it compulsory that you use `<slot>`?
Vue comes with a directive called `<component>` for loading components [dinamically](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components), you can pass your component using the `is` special attribute.

```
<template>
<div>
    <component :is="dynamicComponent">
</div>
</template>
```

The script:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    dynamicComponent(){
      return Comp2 //the class, not the instance
    }
  }
}
```